# Relevance of tags on job postings

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I noticed the following job posting:

[image: job posting]

As you can see it has `java` and `mysql` tags.

After I followed [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102721/full-stack-software-engineer-midas-education?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=ad&utm_campaign=large-sidebar-orange-remote) I saw a job description that required neither Java nor MySQL.

So, where do these tags come from?

Answer (score 3):

I certainly can't vouch for the accuracy of the listing, but it does say:

> 2+ years experience designing and developing Java web applications/services

There doesn't appear to be any mention of a database in the listing, so there's no reason to think it's *not* MySQL.

Like Dean said, it's up to the employers themselves, or their recruiters, to setup the tags on the job. Sometimes our sales or support team members, and occasionally even developers, will help, but we largely rely on employers to give us accurate information.

Comment: Yep, missed that.

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah, I do agree the listing could be a lot more explicit though. Someone will still look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Employers are responsible for entering these tags and they are *supposed* to relate to the technologies used for the job.

I'll get our customer support folks to confirm with the client whether they got these right or not. It would appear they actually meant `javascript` rather than `java`. Not sure where `mysql` comes in here.

Also, you can use the 
[image: flag a problem] link in the sidebar to submit issues with a listing and it'll get picked up by our support team directly.

Thanks for the report.